# sms text messages to mobile phone in php

Tags: php, sms

Can someone provides with the tutorial on how to send sms text messages to mobile phone with 11-digit phone number  and not 10-digit phone number using any free gateway?

Or is there any way I can develop my own using [php](/questions/tagged/php)?

Thank you.

Comment: Google is your best friend. I asked it "php sms" and it gave me [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php/). Hope this one helps.

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383469/sms-text-message-sending-via-php?rq=1. This will help you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have an **SMS API Provider** to achieve what you are trying to do.
The API Provider even gives you a readymade PHP code for making the calls to their API.

Also,

Have a look at **[TextMagic](http://www.textmagic.com/)**
and there is a wrapper available [here](https://code.google.com/p/textmagic-sms-api-php/)

Something like this

```
$api = new TextMagicAPI(array(
    "username" => "your_user_name",
    "password" => "your_API_password", 
));

$text = "Hello world!";
$phones = array(9991234567);
$is_unicode = true;

$api->send($text, $phones, $is_unicode)
```