# PHP send sms via smtp

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

Is there a way to send sms via smtp or without using sms gateway.
Or Is there a way to send sms without cost in php?

Please give code example in php.

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383469/sms-text-message-sending-via-php

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

The same way you need access to the internet via a provider, you need access to the "phonenetwork" which is normally reached by connecting to a sms gateway.

There are some companies though, which provide apis which grant access to use their gateways - but i don't think they provide it for free -  at least not if you want to send many sms.

And yes, some also have smtp apis. You send your sms-message to their server via e-mail and their server takes the mail content and sends the sms by connecting to their sms gateway...

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.If I use smtp,Am I need to pay for sms gateway ?As I understand It will be free. And then can I send sms with free of charge.

Comment: Well, the company you are sending the sms to needs to buy some hardware, make a program which connects to the gateway and sends your mails to the gateway and they will as well have to pay money to their provider for sending sms... The question is: why should they give it for free? - I am not saying that there are no companies which give that service for free. but will they still exist next week and how many sms will you be able to send and i suppose there will be at least some commercial in the sms included or you have to sell your soul and other data for free ;)