# Sending SMS from PHP

Tags: php, sms

How to send an SMS from a web server written in PHP?

Comment: http://www.ozekisms.com/php-sms-api-asp-sms-api/index_p_php_q_ow_page_number_e_327opt.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMS from web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432944/sms-from-web-application)

Comment: The other (still existing) dupe is: [any good php tutorial on how to send sms to phones?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1022597/367456)

Comment: Because this still shows up at search results I would have liked to add a sample request like this one: https://github.com/46elks/46elks-getting-started/blob/master/code-examples/PHP/sendsms.php that I think would have been helpful to others wondering the same thing and actually looking for PHP example with code.

Comment: Great question! Thanks for posing it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Clickatell](https://clickatell.com) is a popular SMS gateway. It works in 200+ countries.

Their API offers a choice of connection options via: HTTP/S, SMPP, SMTP, FTP, XML, SOAP. Any of these options can be used from php.

The HTTP/S method is as simple as this:

`http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?to=NUMBER&msg=Message+Body+Here`

The SMTP method consists of sending a plain-text e-mail to: `sms@messaging.clickatell.com`, with the following body:

```
user: xxxxx
password: xxxxx
api_id: xxxxx
to: 448311234567
text: Meet me at home
```

You can also test the gateway (incoming and outgoing) for free from your browser

Comment: I've tried to use the HTTP/S method and it is returning a message tracking ID with some code. But I'm not receiving any text. Why is this?

Comment: These Links are alas dead now - try https://www.clickatell.com/pricing-and-coverage/message-pricing/#step-1

Comment: why do I need to use some server if it is not free..

Answer (score 17):

**PHP by itself has no SMS module or functions and doesn't allow you to send SMS.**

SMS ( Short Messaging System) is a GSM technology an you need a GSM provider that will provide this service for you and may have an PHP API implementation for it.

Usually people in telecom business use [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) to handle calls and sms programming.

Answer (score 4):

You need to subscribe to a SMS gateway. There are thousands of those (try searching with google) and they are usually not free. For example [this one](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9522-PHP-Send-SMS-messages-with-Spring-Edge-API.html) has support for PHP.