# How to send SMS in PHP?

Tags: php, configuration, mobile, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending SMS from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939689/sending-sms-from-php)

I would like to make and develop a system module in my web site that has the feature of informing the customers with updates in their data stored in our database.

How I can do that in PHP ? what are the configuration and the code needed to accomplish that ?
Did anyone try that before ? what are the necessary steps needed to achieve that ?
Do I need to subscribe in a Mobile Services Company to use and activate the service in my web site ? How much does it cost and how to do that ?

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=send+sms+in+php

Comment: yes I do not notice it is the same but lucky to have new answers here :)

Comment: No offense, but afaik there is a big fat page coming up lately for new users that tells them to search existing questions first. In addition, when composing the question, SO will give you a list of possible duplicates. Did you, by any chance, use the search function or look at the suggestions before asking the question? And if you did, why dont you tell us why all these other questions dont answer your question? Right now, your question is pretty general. There is no point in having new answers when they basically just reiterate what was already said in the other questions. Just kind advice.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment But I really did not notice the previous one especially that the title is different. Anyhow, Next time, I will make sure No Duplicates is there and it is good to have new answers other than the previous ones. I appreciate your words :)

Comment: I hope there is a way to merge the two answers of the duplicate questions in this useful website so that it will be usefu and good for many number of all. @Pekka I would like to thank you for your good answers and your good memory in discovering duplicate questions and answers and I hope to get new answers from you . Thank you again.

Comment: I would like to know the policy in case of Duplicates. Should I delete the question or its answers will be merged automatically with old question in case of the deletion of my question ?? thanks for reply.

Comment: @user +1 for caring about what to do with duplicates. There is a merging feature but I think only moderators can use it. I think it's okay the way it is currently, I wouldn't delete it because there is useful content here already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look for costs by yourself because they depend on where you live.
To send message I'd look for companies that make it for you. It will cost you around 15 cents for SMS.

If you want to make it by your own then look here http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/sms/ .

Comment: thank you, it is a useful article ..

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the volume of messages you expect to send. If it will be more than 10,000 per day, then you probably want to run your own SMS/WAP gateway using appropriate providers (i.e. connecting directly to the higher volume service providers). Note that running your own gateway will also facilitate the 2 other methods of sending messages - but in those cases you let a third party handle the routing.

For less than this, life will be a lot simpler if you rely on a service aggregator - they usually provide an SMTP or HTTP interface. The API details are usually specific to the aggregator.

While there are an increasing number of aggregators catering to the low volume market, if you're expecting to send less than 300 texts / month, then the most cost effective option may be to use a GSM modem (most modern mobiles will connect directly to a PC and act as such).

How much it costs depends on where you are, where your customers are and the quality of service you require - but for a origin - billed SMS with low priority routing and reasonable volumes, expect to pay something in the region of 0.04-0.1 UKP).