# Sending SMS to users

Tags: php, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatic SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)
>   [Sending SMS from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939689/sending-sms-from-php)

I have users. They've entered their mobile phones. How can I send them notifications to their mobile phones (SMS) when I want? I've found nice service (http://www.zeepmobile.com/), but they send SMS only to people who subscribed to them. I need to implement it with PHP. Thanks.

Comment: If you implement the API, you should be able to send SMS messages to anyone.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here - could you clarify?

Comment: Have you read http://www.zeepmobile.com/developers/getting_started/embed_settings_panel ?

Answer (score 0):

I used openmarket API to send SMS to anybody. They have pretty good documentation and SMS SDK http://www.openmarket.com/resources/sdk-download/ for different languages. Also they can send MMS too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try www.bulksms.com and send out SMS as an email. Just make sure your country is supported and yes you will need to pay a few cents for every SMS. But sending SMS is pretty easy. All what you need to do is send out email to:

[COUNTRY_CODE][CELL_PHONE_NUMBER]@bulksms.com

After purchasing some SMS's on BulkSMS.com you will also have some kind of admmin panel there. You need to set a password which you need to later use it as a email subject in order to send out SMS.

With PHP you can use mail function like:

```
mail("038640123456@bulksms.com", "Subject + [YOUR_CHOSEN_PASS]", "This is test SMS..");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Tropo.com](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp) its nice, easy to implement and less expensive.